# How can I throttle calls of methods of a react component via RxJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rxjs, dom-events

I have the following TSX code:

```
public render() {    
  return (
    <div onWheel={this.onWheel}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

private onWheel(event: React.SyntheticEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {...}
```

I want to throttle `this.onWheel` calls using [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/throttle.md) to prevent frequent method calls.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward solution is to use a Subject:

- Create the subject and subscribe to it with throttling on component mount
- Call its 'next' method on every event
- Unsubscribe on component unmount

#### Code with removed TS symbols:

```
render() {    
  return (
    <div onWheel={e => this.onWheel$.next(e)}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.onWheel$ = new Rx.Subject();
    this.onWheel$.throttleTime(500).subscribe(this.onWheel);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.onWheel$.unsubscribe();
}

onWheel(event) {...}
```

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/79499/) for a working example.